# Partially installed app stuck and cannot be unistalled

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore

After updating my iPad 3 to the latest version of iOS (9.2.1 I think, this was in February 2016) one of my apps needed to be updated. It partially installed then got stuck with the status graphic about 50%. After a day or two I tried to delete it and despite me acknowledging the warning "this will also delete the app's data" nothing happened.

So I'm stuck with an app that's not installed and can't be removed. And I still get notifications from the app, but listed as some generic notification type.

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Definitely try restarting the device if you haven't.

Answer (score 2):

The way to solve it at [Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4437912?start=0&tstart=0):

Try deleting the waiting icons - tap and hold down on an icon until it wiggles - the tap the X on the icon to delete it. Then try to download again. Try swiping across the progress bar as well.

Reboot the iPad by holding down on the <kbd>sleep</kbd> and <kbd>home</kbd> buttons at the same time for about 10-15 seconds until the Apple Logo appears - ignore the red slider - let go of the buttons.

Make sure that you do not have a stalled download in iTunes - a song or podcast.  if you have a download in there that did not finish, complete that one first. Only one thing can download at a time on the iPad so that could be what is causing the problem.

If that doesn't work - sign out of your account, restart the iPad and then sign in again.

`Settings`>`iTunes & App Store`>`Apple ID`. Tap your ID and sign out. Restart the iPad by holding down on the <kbd>sleep</kbd> button until the red slider appears and then slide to shut off. To power up hold the <kbd>sleep</kbd> button until the Apple logo appears and let go of the button.

Go back to `Settings`>`iTunes & App Store`>`Sign in` and then try to update again. Tap one waiting icon only if necessary to start the download stream.